# Как организовать Random без повторений на Java?

Tags: java, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Есть числа с 0 по 23. Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку генерировалось случайное число, которое не встречалось еще как минимум 2 раза?

Comment: Храните 2 прошлых числа. Проверяйте на совпадение, и если совпало - генерите другое новое.

Comment: Как у вас хранятся числа и сколько их может быть? Ровно 24 или хоть 124?

Comment: @Dred Любое количество

Comment: @programator2010. Как вы их передаете? покажите ваш код. Вам предложили несколько решений и все они зависят от того, какие у вас входные данные.

Comment: Число не должно выпадать два или три раза? Подряд или вообще? Уточните пожалуйста условие и приведите пример ситуации, которой Вы хотите избежать, а то в ответах люди гадают.

Answer (score 3):

Я понял твой вопрос как: "создать список из 24 рандомных(от 0 до 24) чисел, чтобы каждое число не повторялось более 2 раз". И действительно - два сета. В каждом уникальные числа от 0 до 24. Максимальное кол-во повторений - 2 раза на число. Просто доставайте отсюда(res) значения по необходимости.

```
ArrayList<Integer> first = new ArrayList<>(12);
ArrayList<Integer> second = new ArrayList<>(12);
int randTemp;
while(first.size()!=12){
    randTemp=getMyRandMethod();
    if(!first.contains(randTemp)){
          first.add(randTemp);
    }
} 
while(second.size()!=12){
    randTemp=getMyRandMethod();
    if(!second.contains(randTemp)){
          second.add(randTemp);
    };
}
ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(24);
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
    res.add(first.get(i));
    res.add(second.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Во первых это не скомпилируется т.к. у `Set` отсутствует метод `get`, во вторых идею я все равно не уловил

Comment: Блин, прошу прощения. Нужно было проверить.

Comment: все что Вы написали можно сделать проще, но все равно остается вопрос открытым, как брать значения из этого массива?

Comment: Только сейчас дописал (на телефоне) нормальную версию

Comment: Можете как-то объяснить что делает этот код? Насколько я понял тут сливаются два списка с неповторяющимися случайными числами. Неясно почему в `res` числа не будут повторяться.

Comment: @defaultlocale Я понял его вопрос как "создать список из 24 рандомных(от 0 до 24) чисел, чтобы каждое число не повторялось более 2 раз". И действительно - два сета. В каждом уникальные числа от 0 до 24. Максимальное кол-во повторений - 2 раза на число

Comment: @Miron Понятно, спасибо! Может это прописать в тексте, а то условие в вопросе довольно размытое?

Comment: @defaultlocale изменил описание

Answer (score 3):

Метод, не требующий повторной генерации, гарантирующий, что в каждой тройке последовательных чисел нет повтора (т.е. задачу я понимаю так же, как  Kromster в комментарии)

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/gVu7g0) с ограничением 8, а не 24 (для более лёгкого контроля)

```
    int n = 8;
    final Random rnd = new Random();
    int lastlast = rnd.nextInt(n);
    int last = (lastlast + 1 + rnd.nextInt(n - 1)) % n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        int r = (lastlast + 1 + rnd.nextInt(n - 2)) % n;
        if (r == last)
            r = (lastlast + n - 1) % n;
        lastlast = last;
        last = r;
        System.out.println(last);
    }
```

[Python версия](https://ideone.com/XVnd3u) с выводом гистограммы распределения для контроля равномерности

Comment: авансом поставил плюс, потом полез смотреть как это работает и обнаружил что Ваш вариант в ideone не выводит числа больше 7

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Потому что в моём примере ограничение <8 `(int n)`,  чтобы легче заметить ошибки ;)

Comment: стоит наверное об этом написать т.к. я удумал в этом хитрую логику =) вроде разделенного на 3 сегмента диапазона т.к. 24/3 = 8

Answer (score 1):

Реализация того что предложил товарищ @Kromster:

```
public class Rand24 extends Random {

    LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();

    public synchronized int next24() {
        int result;
        do result = nextInt(24);
        while (l.contains(result));
        l.add(result);
        if (l.size() == 3) l.removeFirst();
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Вариант похитрее, в нем отсутствует повторная генерация и в целом код понятнее:

В листе лежат 24 возможных значения, берем случайное из диапазона 0-21 и перемещаем его в конец листа. Недостаток - заранее исключены 2 числа, ситуацию можно слегка улучшить расставив элементы в исходном массиве не по порядку.

```
public class Rand24_2 extends Random {

    List<Integer> values = IntStream.range(0, 24).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

    public synchronized int next24() {
        int rnd = values.remove(nextInt(values.size() - 2));
        values.add(rnd);
        return rnd;
    }
}
```

[https://ideone.com/](https://ideone.com/9HEjAV)

Comment: @Miron в плане формирования случайной последовательности? Наверное вполне, только для решения недостаточно массива..

Comment: Создаётся массив. Туда суются все числа от 0 до 24. Ловим рандомное число от 0 до 24. Это у нас индекс у массива. Меняем местами элемент по этому индексу и последний элемент.  Все полученные элементы суются в конец(ну не совсем, но вы поняли). Теперь у нас 23 элемента(для обработки, но в реале 24). Ловим рандомное число от 0 до 23... Повторяем, пока не дойдем до конца. Вуаля - у нас есть готовый массив. Сделанный за линейное время. Вот. Теперь и динамический не нужен

Comment: @Miron это не так, тк это не случайная последовательность, грубо говоря я знаю на 100% какое число выпадет последним, если просто брать значения по порядку из перемешанных 24 значений

Comment: А, вы про это. Можно сделать так же, как я сделал в своем ответе

Comment: Почему знаете? Оно же рандомно берет. Оно может как первый элемент засунуть, так и второй

Comment: @Miron я не понял последнее сообщение

Comment: Вы говорите про то, что зная предыдущие 23 вы можете подсказать 24?

Comment: А, я трактовал вопрос по иному. Нужны 24 числа от 0 до 24. Каждое число в последовательности не должно повторяться более 2 раз. Автор вопроса, конечно, по-китайски написал...

Comment: Я все же склоняюсь к тому, что он имел именно это. Не мог же он такую ерунду спрашивать (не баньте)

Comment: Тот случай когда с `int last; int lastButOne;` код читается лучше чем с `LinkedList l`

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще 1 вариант
Здесь, вы в Map вносите свое число, как ключ, а в качестве значения количество его выводов. Если у вас допустимо, чтобы число повторялось 2 раза ставьте `maxCount = 3`

```
public void rand() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    int maxCount = 2;
    while (true) {
        int number = new Random().nextInt(23);
        if (!map.containsKey(number)) {
            map.put(number, 1);
            showNumber(number);
            break;
        } else {
            Integer value = map.get(number);
            if (value < maxCount) {
                showNumber(number);
            } else {
                value++;
                map.put(number, value);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void showNumber(int number) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант

```
public final class RandomGenerator {
    private final int[] numbers;
    private int size;

    public RandomGenerator(int size) {
        numbers = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            numbers[i] = i;

        this.size = size;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] array, int i1, int i2) {
        int value = array[i1];
        array[i1] = array[i2];
        array[i2] = value;
    }

    public synchronized int getNumber() {
        if (size == 0)
            size = numbers.length;


        int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(size);
        int value = numbers[index];
        size--;
        swap(numbers, size, index);

        return value;
    }
}
```